# PubsubIO.Read + exactly once delivery

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

With the [2.2 Dataflow SDK](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/) is it possible to achieve exactly-once delivery using the [messageId](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage) field that Pubsub automatically applies? Or is this perhaps even a default behavior?

It seems like this normally might be possible with `PubsubIO.Read.withIdAttribute` but I don't have control over the published message, so I was hoping to use the messageId field.

In the old [1.x docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pubsub-io) it states:

> In addition, you can achieve exactly once processing of Pub/Sub message streams, as PubsubIO de-duplicates messages based on custom message identifiers or identifiers assigned by Pub/Sub.

Where the last part there kind of hints that the default behavior of the read might inherently use the messageId for exactly-once delivery purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both 1.x and 2.2 are same in this regard. Both provide exactly-once processing semantics. Pubsub message id is used in both.

Note that it exactly-once "processing" and exactly-once "delivery" are not always the same. Delivery often implies sink to an external system, which is outside the scope of a Dataflow pipeline. A sink might have duplicate writes when there are retries in the pipeline.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to any documentation that states where it would use the messageId for the exactly-once processing? Also, if it provides this exactly-once processing by default, what is the point of ever using `PubsubIO.Read.withIdAttribute`?

Comment: I did find [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/07/after-lambda-exactly-once-processing-in-cloud-dataflow-part-3-sources-and-sinks) which seems to describe that behaviors I was referring to. Thanks again

Comment: You are right. The default documentation in Apache Beam refers to open source PubsubIO and is not very useful[1]. Dataflow pipelines use own implementation of it (with a bit of server side component). I will file bug about how to to communicate it to the user.
[1]: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.Read.html#withIdAttribute-java.lang.String-

Comment: I filed an internal bug report to improve documentation for PubSubIO.